# Friend and myself need software to work on a project in live time

Tags: collaboration

A friend and I are looking to work on a web application together. However, we require a program that will allow both of us to work on the application in real time and with independent control.

I looked into Atoms teletype. However, only one user can be doing something at a time and can view the entire project.

Requirements:

- Both parties are able to see the entire project structure and layout.
- Have their own control
- Real-time viewing and editing

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Related question: [Real-time code collaboration](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10580/23377).

Answer (score 1):

If you want real-time collaborative editing you might look into Gobby (https://gobby.github.io/).  It's not an IDE, or a version control system, but if multiple people really have to be editing the same file at the same time, it works well.