# What is a good online IDE that has real-time collaboration?

Tags: ide

I'm thinking about starting a project where there will be multiple files and need to be able to collaborate in real-time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real-time code collaboration](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/real-time-code-collaboration) (the question is slightly different but your answer can be found there).

Comment: Your question does not tell us much - what programming language? Free? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [GitPod?](https://www.gitpod.io/)
All you do is navigate to a GitHub repository that you own and add "gitpod.io#" to the URL and it automatically works. It's actually amazing.